# remove integrated toolbar from googleMap fragment in Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to build a simple app with GoogleMap API and I have custom tool bar.

The problem: I want to remove the default toolbar from the fragment.

activity .xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.BillboardsMap"
android:orientation="vertical">
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar_back_billbo"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar_back_billbo"
/>
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

onCreate function:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityBillboardsMapBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}
```

Is it possible to remove the toolbar with the title "BillboardsMap"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this activity or you are creating inside fragment?

Comment: activity @Sandesh

Comment: Add code which I have added below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

STEP 1 -In style.xml or theme.xml add this custom new style.

```
<style name="NoToolbar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

STEP 2- In manifest.xml add this code for your activity.

```
<activity
            ....
            android:theme="@style/NoToolbar"   //ADD this line for your activity class

 > </activity>
```

Comment: thank you my friend but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

> **Just add this to your map fragment.**

```
 override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.hide()
        }
    
        override fun onStop() {
            super.onStop()
            (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.show()
        }
```